# Designing time Sheet grid a like web User control using Repeater

Tags: repeater

I want to building the time sheet grid a like web user control using Repeater controls

Layout is like this

Activty code | Activity Name | 16th Mar 2009|17th Mar 2009|.....n

101       Activity1          10 hours   10 hours...... n

Note here column is n columns will be decided based on application setting.

Can any one help me in doing this type of Web user control using Repeater controls.

Comment: What have you done so far? What are the current coding errors?

Comment: i have not started creating i want to know how to do this , like this header will need to added dynamically right row is not a problem i can use the itemtemplate of repeater which will be called for each row in the datasource.I hope u got wat im looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this.](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/590905-dynamic-repeater-itemtemplates)

Comment: thanks tom, the msdn link for creating the template that helped me.